# How to style BlockQuotes in Android TextViews?

Tags: android, textview

Is there a way to format the `<BlockQuote>` HTML tag within an Android TextView? WebViews are an option if I can easily manipulate 3 columns with images, ads and multiple vertical scrolling pages.

The text view obviously handles the tag, I get an ugly blue line to denote the blockquote. Is there a way to change the color of the line or better yet provide my own line image?

Answer (score 22):

If you use `android.text.Html#fromHtml` to build your `android.text.Spannable`, your `blockquote` will be implemented with `android.text.style.QuoteSpan`. It is this `QuoteSpan` that doesn't allow configuration.

The easiest solution would be to search for all the `QuoteSpan`s in your `Spannable` and replace them:

```
private void replaceQuoteSpans(Spannable spannable) {
    QuoteSpan[] quoteSpans = spannable.getSpans(0, spanned.length(), QuoteSpan.class);
    for (QuoteSpan quoteSpan : quoteSpans) {
        int start = spannable.getSpanStart(quoteSpan);
        int end = spannable.getSpanEnd(quoteSpan);
        int flags = spannable.getSpanFlags(quoteSpan);
        spannable.removeSpan(quoteSpan);
        spannable.setSpan(new CustomQuoteSpan(
                MY_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
                MY_STRIPE_COLOR,
                MY_STRIPE_WIDTH,
                MY_GAP_WIDTH),
            start,
            end,
            flags);
    }
}
```

with a `CustomQuoteSpan` class like:

```
/**
 * android.text.style.QuoteSpan hard-codes the strip color and gap. :(
 */
public class CustomQuoteSpan implements LeadingMarginSpan, LineBackgroundSpan {
    private final int backgroundColor;
    private final int stripeColor;
    private final float stripeWidth;
    private final float gap;

    public CustomQuoteSpan(int backgroundColor, int stripeColor, float stripeWidth, float gap) {
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        this.stripeColor = stripeColor;
        this.stripeWidth = stripeWidth;
        this.gap = gap;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLeadingMargin(boolean first) {
        return (int) (stripeWidth + gap);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawLeadingMargin(Canvas c, Paint p, int x, int dir, int top, int baseline, int bottom,
                                  CharSequence text, int start, int end, boolean first, Layout layout) {
        Paint.Style style = p.getStyle();
        int paintColor = p.getColor();

        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        p.setColor(stripeColor);

        c.drawRect(x, top, x + dir * stripeWidth, bottom, p);

        p.setStyle(style);
        p.setColor(paintColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawBackground(Canvas c, Paint p, int left, int right, int top, int baseline, int bottom, CharSequence text, int start, int end, int lnum) {
        int paintColor = p.getColor();
        p.setColor(backgroundColor);
        c.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, p);
        p.setColor(paintColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will add tip. To color text in quote span add below code belose setting quote span  `spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFF5C5C5C), start, end, flags);`